# Templating parser

Tags: regex, parsing

I'd like to create a parser which substitutes text like the following (similar to MediaWiki's syntax):

```
some text {{template|parameter1|parameter2}} some text
```

The regex should match the text between the curly braces (split to groups for template name and parameter). This is what I've already got.

Where I don't get further is infinitely nested templates:

```
some text {{template|{{subtemplate|st-parameter}}|parameter2}} some text
```

The text should be replaced from the innermost to the outermost template. I'm not sure how to write a regex that doesn't break at the first closing braces in the example above. Best would be if the regex only matches for the innermost template (without `{{` and `}}` inside). Where to start?

Comment: What flavour of regex are you looking for?

Comment: PCRE is what I'm using, but if it is much easier in any other regex I'll appreciate your answer, too.

Comment: Many language support some form of PCRE, but there are still (small) differences between the implementations: it's best to just say what language you're using (or going to use).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're running up against [the limitations of regular languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475804/regular-expression-for-math-operations-with-parentheses). If you're doing things like full-on recursive embedding, without any easy tricks to tell you where the deepest level of nesting is (like Ingo's suggestion of no braces), you want to use a context-free grammar.

Answer (score 0):

You want to match the innermost thing only, that means the text may not contain braces (but is enclosed in braces):

```
\{([^{}]*)\}
```

Your result will be in matcher group 1.

Comment: The text may contain braces but not any valid other template (ex. `{{template|aa{{|bb}}`, so `{{template|aa{{}}|bb}}` but not `{{template|aa{{subtemplate}}|bb}}` should be allowed), but good start, thanks.

Comment: What makes something a valid template?