# How to turn several "Sqrt[some text inside]" into several Sqrt(some text inside) , I mean from [] into ()

Tags: java, regex

I got the following Expression that can look like this (the amount of Sqrt[XXX] is unknow)

```
Sqrt[A+B] + Sqrt[Min[A,B]] * Min[Sqrt[C],D]
```

and I want to turn all  `Sqrt[XXX]` into `Sqrt(XXX)` ,  I want to replace the `[]` brackets of the `Sqrt` into `()` brackets

so the above example will look like

`Sqrt(A+B) + Sqrt(Min[A,B]) * Min[Sqrt(C),D]`

I don't want to "hurt" the other `[]` brackets in the expression (like the ones next to `Min`)

How can I do it with regex ?

Comment: You can't do it with regular expressions, see accepted answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475804/regular-expression-for-math-operations-with-parentheses

Comment: @MK I fear with backtracking he generally could (the difference between sensible REs and the mess we have now thanks to perl~). But I agree that it's not the way to go.

Comment: @Voo I'm pretty sure you can't even with backtracking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using iteration over the characters in the String. First look for the index of `Sqrt[` and then look for the matching closing bracket.

Here is some sample code:

```
final String s = "Sqrt[A+B] + Sqrt[Min[A,B]] * Min[Sqrt[C],D]";
final char[] charArray = s.toCharArray();

int index = s.indexOf("Sqrt[");
while (index != -1) {
    final int open = index + 4;
    charArray[open] = '(';

    // look for closing bracket
    int close;
    int matching = 0;
    for (close = open + 1; close < charArray.length; close++) {
        char c = charArray[close];
        if (c == ']') {
            if (matching == 0) {
                break;
            }
            matching--;
        } else if (c == '[') {
            matching++;
        }
    }
    charArray[close] = ')';
    index = s.indexOf("Sqrt[", index + 1);
}
System.out.println(new String(charArray));
```

I have not tested it properly, so please do.

Comment: (+1) I have not attempted to test the code, but I think this type of approach is more suited to the problem than using regular expression.

Comment: Yep that should work, although one really should add a testcase with `Sqrt[A + Sqrt[A]]` as well. But that should work as well without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Using the given format of the source string, you can do it with 3 regular expressions. The trick here is to "rename" the square brackets belonging to the `Min` function and restoring them later on. You would do something like:

```
s/Min\[([^[]+)\]/Min\{$1\}/g;
s/Qsrt\[([^[]+)\]/Sqrt\($1\)/g;
s/Min\{([^{]+)\}/Min\[$1\]}/g;
```

For the general case a parser would be the way to go. For special cases like this using a trick might work :-).