# Grep and replace only works half way

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, grep

**I wrote this:**

```
grep -lr --include=*.js "eval(function" sitemap.js | xargs sed -i.bak 's/}eval(function[^;]*;/{\n/g'
```

**This is the code I would like to remove:**

```
}eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return c.toString(a)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('7 3(e,t,n,a,o,i,m){e.5=o,e[o]=e[o]||3(){(e[o].q=e[o].q||[]).b(p)},e[o].l=e[o].l||+6 4,i=t.8(n),i.9=1,i.c=a,m=t.d(n)[0],m.f.g(i,m)}(h,j,"k","//2.r.s/2/1.u","2");',31,31,'||tj|function|Date|alogObjectName|new|void|createElement|asyn||push|src|getElementsByTagName||parentNode|insertBefore|window||document|script|||||arguments||tongjj|info||js'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

**My results were this:** (only removed some. the first bit)

```
if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)r[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return r[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('7 3(e,t,n,a,o,i,m){e.5=o,e[o]=e[o]||3(){(e[o].q=e[o].q||[]).b(p)},e[o].l=e[o].l||+6 4,i=t.8(n),i.9=1,i.c=a,m=t.d(n)[0],m.f.g(i,m)}(h,j,"k","//2.r.s/2/1.u","2");',31,31,'||tj|function|Date|alogObjectName|new|void|createElement|asyn||push|src|getElementsByTagName||parentNode|insertBefore|window||document|script|||||arguments||tongjj|info||js'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

What is causing my RegEx to break and how can I fix it?

**GOAL:**
I would like to remove that entire EVAL() string/line

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I would like to remove that entire EVAL() string/line

Comment: Rather than describing the expected output, can you show it? I don't understand what you want.

Comment: Does my question not adequately describe my current results in my attempt to achieve the expect output?

Comment: How many times does this string occur in your input? This may be a better use case for the delete key.

Comment: Not gonna happen. Regular expressions cannot match nested parentheses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression for math operations with parentheses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475804/regular-expression-for-math-operations-with-parentheses)

Comment: Your `[^;]*;` matches `}eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,r){e=function(c){return c.toString(a)};` and that is deleted. Is this what you want or do you want to delete more?

Comment: `I would like to remove that entire EVAL() string/line` then use: `sed -i.bak 's/}eval(function.*/{/g'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eval() call closes on the last parenthesis of the line. You can't match the brackets and parenthesis with sed. You might need to make a program for that.

Otherwise, open your code in a bracket matching editor and remove it manually.