# regex for cos/sin/tan with inner brackets inside

Tags: java, regex

Cant't find an appropriate pattern for this kind of math expression:   `2*-5+ sin(1.5*4)+(28- 3^4-(cos(3+(19*3)+1+(6/2))/2+tan(1+cos(1+9))-6/3+2.3*3.3345)+1)+1)-(4/2)` where there is **(or not)** inner brackets inside cos.
desirable result is:

```
 1. cos(3+(19*3)+1+(6/2))
 2. cos(1+9)
```

i tried `cos\(.+?\)` , but i get only `cos(3 + (19*3)`. If i'm trying a greedy quantifier i get the whole string till the last `)`

thank you in advance!

Comment: Algebraic expressions are not a regular language. Use a proper parser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5475880/5812121

Comment: Well, the [current duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475804/regular-expression-for-math-operations-with-parentheses) question deals with any `[...]` unit in an expression, while this question asks how to only get units like `cos(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a method accepting the string to parse, a string before the starting balanced symbol, the character delimiters and a flag to include or exclude the delimiters (markers).

See the [Java IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/nQCeoU):

```
public static List<String> getBalancedStr(String s, String strBefore, Character markStart, 
                                 Character markEnd, Boolean includeMarkers) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?=(\\b\\Q" + strBefore + markStart.toString() + "\\E.*))").matcher(s);
    List<String> subTreeList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (m.find()) {
        int level = 0;
        int lastOpenBracket = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < m.group(1).length(); i++) {
            char c = m.group(1).charAt(i);
            if (c == markStart) {
                level++;
                if (level == 1) {
                    lastOpenBracket = (includeMarkers ? i : i + 1);
                }
            }
            else if (c == markEnd) {
                if (level == 1) {
                    if (includeMarkers) {
                        subTreeList.add(strBefore + m.group(1).substring(lastOpenBracket, i + 1));
                    } else {
                        subTreeList.add(m.group(1).substring(lastOpenBracket, i));
                    }
                    break;
                }
                level--;
            }
        }
    }
    return subTreeList;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
String s = "2*-5+ sin(1.5*4)+(28- 3^4-(cos(3+(19*3)+1+(6/2))/2+tan(1+cos(1+9))-6/3+2.3*3.3345)+1)+1)-(4/2)";  
System.out.println("cos: " + getBalancedStr(s, "cos", '(', ')', true)); 
// cos: [cos(3+(19*3)+1+(6/2)), cos(1+9)]
System.out.println("sin: " + getBalancedStr(s, "sin", '(', ')', true)); 
// sin: [sin(1.5*4)]
System.out.println("tan: " + getBalancedStr(s, "tan", '(', ')', true)); 
// tan: [tan(1+cos(1+9))]
```

Note that the method compiles a regex - `"(?=(\\b\\Q" + strBefore + markStart.toString() + "\\E.*))"` - that will match `cos` or `sin` only as a whole word (since `\b` is a word boundary) and the `.*` will match up to the end of the line. If you want to support multiple line input, use `(?s)` in front: `"(?s)\\b\\Q" + strBefore + markStart.toString() + "\\E.*"`. Since the pattern is in a capturing group inside an unanchored positive lookahead, we collect all overlapping matches, and will only get 1 balanced substring at each match (since after we have found a corresponding matching closing delimiter, we break out of the `for` loop.